# a measures for comparing two values and counting the result in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, etl, measure

How can I write a measure to count the number of userID for which **sum(x1)** is equal to **count(order_id)**, in Power BI?

For example, my data table is:

| userID | x1 | order_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 141 | 1 | 719 |
| 172 | 0 | 616 |
| 172 | 0 | 189 |
| 172 | 0 | 2211 |
| 172 | 0 | 317 |
| 1103 | 1 | 98 |
| 1103 | 1 | 213 |
| 1103 | 1 | 15 |
| 2524 | 0 | 4902 |
| 2524 | 1 | 3620 |

and I use table visual of power bi for this, to explain my mean:

| userID | sum(x1) | count(order_id) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 141 | 1 | 1 |
| 172 | 0 | 4 |
| 1103 | 3 | 3 |
| 2524 | 1 | 2 |

Note that the userID column is one of the columns in my data table, and calculating sum(x1) and count(order_id) in this sample is by Power BI default features.

The result for this sample should be 2. I need a measure that returns 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Measure1 = 
VAR _base1 =
    SUMMARIZE ( 'Table 1', 'Table 1'[userID] )
VAR _base2 =
    ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table 1', 'Table 1'[userID] )
VAR _ct =
    ADDCOLUMNS ( _base1, "X", CALCULATE ( COUNT ( 'Table 1'[order_id] ), _base2 ) )
VAR _sum =
    ADDCOLUMNS ( _base1, "X", CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table 1'[x1] ), _base2 ) )
VAR _nt =
    NATURALINNERJOIN ( _sum, _ct )
RETURN
    COUNTROWS ( _nt )
```

[image: Solution]

**or**

```
Measure4 =
VAR _1 =
    COUNTX (
        VALUES ( 'Table 1'[userID] ),
        VAR _base =
            ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table 1', 'Table 1'[userID] )
        VAR _1 =
            CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table 1'[x1] ), _base )
        VAR _2 =
            CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( 'Table 1' ), _base )
        VAR _3 =
            IF ( _1 = _2, 1 )
        RETURN
            _3
    )
RETURN
    _1
```

[image: Solution2]

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
count_valid_rows =
VAR sum_x1_table =
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS ( 'table'[userID], 'table', "sumx1", SUM ( 'table'[x1] ) )
VAR count_orderId_table =
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
        'table'[userID],
        'table',
        "countOfOrders", COUNT ( 'table'[x1] )
    )
RETURN
    COUNTROWS (
        FILTER (
            NATURALINNERJOIN ( sum_x1_table, count_orderId_table ),
            [sumx1] = [countOfOrders]
        )
    )
```

Docs of the functions used.

[NATURALINNERJOIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/naturalinnerjoin-function-dax)
[SUMMARIZECOLUMNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/summarizecolumns-function-dax)

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion:

```
Count := 
SUMX (
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
        'Table'[userID] , 
        "Sum" , SUM ( 'Table'[x1] ),
        "Count" , COUNT ( 'Table'[order_id] )
    ),
    IF ( [Sum] = [Count] , 1 )
)
```

As you see from the other answers there are heaps of ways to calculate this. I suggest you look over all the suggestions to understand what is going on in each, and then write out your preferred way of dealing with this type of issue after.

Answer (score 0):

Your new measure may looks like this one:

```
calculate( countrows('YourTabel'), FILTER(ALL('YourTabel'), somestatementIfneeded && var __x1 = [x1] var __x2 = [x2] return __x1 = __x2))
```

The main part is to use variable PLACEHOLDER;

Comment: I edited my question. Please check it again. @msta42a